# How can I migrate a phpBB3 forum from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, migration, phpbb

I have a phpBB3 forum running on a server with MySQL 5.5.
I want to migrate the data to a PostgreSQL 9.3 database.

I've looked at various guides and tools they were either

1. Very old or
2. Not specific to phpBB3

Is there a known proven path to do this migration? Last time I tried it I was under a lot of time pressure and I ended up just installing the MySQL server on the new machine, however to conserve resources (RAM!) I'd rather only have one database server running.

Comment: Why do you feel that instructions specific to phpBB3 would help?     I wouldn't imagine that phpBB3 would use different schema for the two databases.

Comment: You're saying I should just use a generic MySQL to PostgreSQL migration tool?

Comment: It is certainly worth a try.   Back up your data first.